# What are these "Personal Isolation Rooms" intended for on the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The 1973 *[Star Trek Blueprints - General Plans](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/star-trek-blueprints.php)* include a considerable number of '**PR**' rooms, listed in the [key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsu1Y.png) as:

> "***Personal Isolation Room[s]***"

They appear extensively on Deck 6 ("*Crew Quarters*"), Desk 7 ("*Main Deck"*), and Deck 16 ("*Medical*") often at the ends of corridors and typically grouped together, with exit

**What are they, and what are they used for?**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hull breach refuges?  Don't actually know, but that's a classic SF trope, going back to Doc Smith...

Comment: @ZeissIkon - That was my assumption. There's a fair number of non-military personnel on the ship and having them traipse off to their quarters every time the ship goes to alert sounds like a nightmare. Better to have them go to the nearest isolation room and sit there quietly until the emergency is over

Comment: Based on secondary hull shape, I'm guessing this is Pike's/Kirk's 1701 Enterprise?  There were significantly fewer non-Starfleet personnel on starships in those days than was the case for Picard's 1701C/1701D.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - Yes the original Enterprise, prior to its refit; https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/star-trek-blueprints.php

Comment: I had those blueprints, in the late 1970s.  Long gone now.  Ben Franklin was right -- "Three removes are the equivalent of a house fire."

Comment: "Isolation rooms" might be just what the term says, rooms to isolate people, for example in case of contagious diseases. On a spaceship that "boldly goes where no man has gone before" - who knows what germs you may encounter. In later eras, like TNG, there were force fields galore, probably even for this purpose. But in earlier eras, specified and pre-prepared rooms would make sense.

Comment: In addition to the military shelters already commented on - The TMP novelization as I recall mentions a lot of new age meditation/ prayer rooms that may also be the intent in 1973.  The modern office space has all sorts of these and micro conference rooms.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck A number of books have references to "isolation rooms" always in the context of sickbay; these do not appear to be the same things.

Comment: "you space happy or something?" - Janice Rand - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Space_happy

Comment: Female crewpersons can shelter from Kirk in them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Or shelter with Kirk...